# what files and packages of ASM do i need to download for bytecode manipulation?

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

what files and packages of ASM do i need to download for bytecode manipulation? & how can i download it run it on terminal on different java files? I'd like to use it to run java files and sort methods and commands that are used in classes. I tried BCEL and couldnt figure it out. I'm out of my depth here so I'm trying to find step by step instructions on how to download and run it for some basic research!

Comment: It's a big complex package capable of a wide variety of tasks, and it takes some getting used to its concepts. But sorry, you can't expect anyone to write a simple tutorial in response to your question. If you were very very specific about exactly what you want to do, then perhaps someone might be able to help, but if it were easy to produce simple instructions then the people writing the documentation would have done so.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you “download it run it on terminal on different java files”? ASM is a *library* which allows to develop your own programs doing bytecode related task.

Comment: sorry! I don't exactly understand how libraries work and how to use them to manipulate bytecode, I'm learning how to use terminal and what exactly bytecode even is for a project I'm doing in an internet and safety class so I'm way out of my depth